# Tangent Line Approximation Using Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am new to Taylor series as a whole and was wondering if someone with a bit more background could validate my thought process in answering the following question.

Question: Does the tangent line to $y=x \ln x$, at any point $p>0$ over-estimate or under-estimate $x \ln x$

Response: $T_1(x) = p\ln(p) + [\ln(p) + 1][x-p]$ As such, we consider the next term in the Taylor series: $${f^{2}(p)}/2! = 1/2p$$

As per Taylor's theorem, $f(x) = T_1(x) + [f^2(p)/2!][x-p]^2$

The term $[f^2(p)/2!][x-p]^2$ is ALWAYS POSITIVE for all p>0 $->$ Implying that the remainder term is positive. Hence the tangent line approximation for $x\ln(x)$, which is equal to $T_1(x)$ is an under-estimation for $y=x\ln(x)$

Comment: With these kinds of problems, having a [graph](http://wolfr.am/1qEqCql) helps as a check.

Comment: @Semiclassical ... lol I can't believe I didn't think of that

More importantly however, as a math student, when I am writing exams/test, I doubt the function I am given will be simple enough so that I can graph them right there on my exam paper

Comment: Sure. It's just a good last check while doing practice. And I don't see anything wrong with what you've written

Comment: @Guest Notice that $f(x)=T_{1}(x)+\frac{1}{2c}(x-p)^2$ where $c$ is between $x$ and $p$ and, as you say, the remainder term $\frac{1}{2c}(x-p)^2$ is positive.

Comment: This can be also shown by $f''(x)=\frac{1}{x} \gt 0$. But, may be, you could also consider the case where $f'(x)=0$ which corresponds to $x=\frac{1}{e}$ and $f=-\frac{1}{e}$ where the tangent is horizontal. But all your work is good !